# ordering legend label GGPLOT2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I could not order legend label. Getting error as below. "P" is generated in Warning msg. Plot is created and saved as 'P' object. but P in error was generated by R. Due to company confidentiality rules , I can not share the data.

```
 WARNING: R: Error: unexpected symbol in:
 WARNING: R: "
 WARNING: R: p"
```

Any suggestion Please? Code is below.

```
p <- p + geom_point((aes(shape=dosech4, color=dosech4)), size=2, position=pd) +
scale_shape_manual(values=c(0, 1,2,5,8,9)) +
scale_color_manual(values=c('green4','blue','red3','magenta')) +
geom_line((aes(color = dosech4, shape = dosech4,
linetype = dosech4)),show.legend = FALSE, size = .4) +
scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1))

#LEGEND
p = p + theme(legend.position= 'bottom', legend.direction = 'horizontal',
          legend.background=element_rect(fill="white", colour="black", size = .8),
          legend.title = element_blank(), 
          legend.text = element_text(size = 10, face = 'bold'))

p = p + scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c('3mg//kg (N= 3)',
       '15mg//kg (N= 3)',  '60mg//kg (N= 6)',  '150mg//kg (N= 6)'))
```

Comment: You don't have to share the actual data if there's confidentiality concerns. A minimal, complete & verifiable example is preferred. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve